# Unable to pass count for table view datasource methods?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here i need to give count for the table view data source methods to display the dictionary items can anyone help me how to pass the count to table view so that how to declare the model class array ?

here i had declared array like this `var cartModel : CartItems?`

here is the code for json download function

```
  func cartItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(cartApi: String){
        let url = URL(string: cartApi)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for item in jsonObj {
                         self.cartModel = CartItems(dict: item as [String : AnyObject])
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                        let totalCount = String(describing: self.cartModel.count)
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("UpdateBadgeNumberNotification"), object: totalCount)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
struct CartItems {

    let itemId :Int
    let sku : String
    let quantity : Int
    let name : String
    let price : Int
    let productType : String
    let quoteId : Int
    let extensionAttributes : [ExtensionAttributes]

    init(dict : [String:Any]) {

        if let arr = dict["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
            var filterArr = [ExtensionAttributes]()
            for obj in arr {
                filterArr.append(ExtensionAttributes(dict: obj))
            }
            self.extensionAttributes = filterArr
        } else {
            self.extensionAttributes = [ExtensionAttributes]()
        }
        self.itemId = dict["items_id"]! as! Int
        self.sku = dict["sku"] as! String
        self.quantity = dict["qty"] as! Int
        self.name = dict["name"] as! String
        self.price = dict["price"] as! Int
        self.productType = dict["product_type"] as! String
        self.quoteId = dict["quote_id"] as! Int
    }
}
```

here is the json data

```
[
    {
        "item_id": 241,
        "sku": "24-MB01",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
        "price": 34,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "3bfc8f55e41cbbb2b3b95346d38f9de1",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "image_url": "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/265x265/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you are going to accomplish. By the way: Why do you cast `[String:Any]` to `[String:AnyObject]`. That's nonsensical. As mentioned a couple of times a JSON dictionary in Swift 3+ is `[String:Any]`, there's no need to cast it. And don't use the `String(describing` initializer for an `Int`

Comment: [
    {
        "item_id": 241,
        "sku": "24-MB01",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
        "price": 34,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "3bfc8f55e41cbbb2b3b95346d38f9de1",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "image_url": "https://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/265x265/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        }
    }
]   i am having a array like this for getting data i had written model class so that how to declare model class to get the products count

Comment: product count means array inside dictionaries count now only 1 it may increase also @vadian

Comment: But in the same controller you can get the number of items anytime with `cartModel.count`

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments. Edit the question

Comment: but by declaring like this var cartModel : CartItems? i am unable to get the count for cartmodel @vadian

Comment: Declare data source arrays **always** as non-optional empty arrays: `var cartModel = [CartItems]()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156622/discussion-between-user-and-vadian).

Comment: how to get extension attributes from dictionary in json data ? @vadian

Comment: it was crashing in table view  datasource method cell for row at indexpath  @vadian

Comment: As I mentioned in the chat that depends on what you want to display. In the array are there multiple entries which contain pictures? Could it be that there are no pictures are all? Programming is a very precise subject. According to the screenshot you have to get the string value from the first object in the array by its key.

Comment: In the extension attributes there will be only one key value pair that is imageurl that i need to display and the image url Only one object will be there every time and nil will not be there @vadian

Comment: But if there is always only one dictionary (with one unique key) in the array why do you use an **array** of dictionaries with **one** object respectively rather than **one** dictionary with **all keys and values**. Your data structure is pretty inefficient. To answer the question you have to write `let imageDict = array.first(where: { $0["image_url"]  != nil }); let imageURL =  imageDict["image_url"] as! String`

Comment: don't know the magento team has delivered like that @vadian

Comment: Maybe the JSON source doesn't have this structure but your code implies it has. Another question and no offense. Apparently you are working on a project for a commercial purpose. Wouldn't it be more efficient to hire a professional programmer?

Comment: no its having the same as i told i posted the json data see above

Comment: So there is always only **one** `extension_attributes` although the plural form suggests there are **many** attributes? If yes why do you use an array and a custom class? That's all very very cumbersome.

Comment: don't know may increase in future i think soo

Comment: still error continues https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrIWz.png @vadian

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what the class or struct `ExtensionAttributes` contains. Please lets stop this here because it's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `cartModel` object from `var cartModel : CartItems?` to `var cartModel = [CartItems]()` and 
replace this line

`self.cartModel = CartItems(dict: item as [String : AnyObject])`

with

`self.cartModel.append(CartItems(dict: item as [String : AnyObject]))`

Now, use `self.cartModel.count`

Comment: bro then how to get the image url from the extension attributes dictionary

Comment: Try using `self.cartModel[indexPath.row]. extensionAttributes.first`

Comment: Brother send your extensionAttributes

Comment: i had mentioned in question itself

Comment: No, there is no defination for ExtensionAttributes

Comment: no i defined but not posted in code here is the code struct ExtensionAttributes {
    
    let imageurl : String
    
    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        self.imageurl = dict["image_url"] as! String
    }
}

Comment: here having image url i need to get and pass to imageview

Comment: Brother you are not parsing your json in correct format (according to your josn posted in your question)